# How to trigger did didReceiveRemoteNotification from UNNotificationContentExtension when UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled is true

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

**Background:**

I have implemented a `UNNotificationContentExtension` so that I can format the APNS data received and render it as per my need as shown below

[image]

I would like user to click on the stars and rate so I have enabled the user interactions on `UNNotificationContentExtension` using

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
        <string>test</string>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionOverridesDefaultTitle</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension</string>
</dict>
```

**Whats the issue?**

Now user can tap on stars and rate it, but because user interaction is enabled no matter wherever user on the notification view, notification does not dismiss and won't handover the data to parent application. So `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called no matter how many times user taps on the custom UI.

**What I wanna achieve?**

I would like the normal iOS notification flow to kick in and handover notification payload to iOS parent app when user taps on any star or taps anywhere in the custom UI. If user taps on star Ill propagate the rating provided else 0 will be passed.

How can I dismiss the notification and trigger parent app `didReceiveRemoteNotification` or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when user clicks on custom UI when `UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out :) Apple introduced `performNotificationDefaultAction()` from iOS 12 onwards.

As per docs

```
    // Opens the corresponding applicaton and delivers it the default notification action response
    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    open func performNotificationDefaultAction()
```

So all I had to do was, once user taps on any of the stars I had to call `performNotificationDefaultAction` programmatically

```
@IBAction func ratingTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        debugPrint("\(sender.tag)")
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 12.0, *) {
            self.extensionContext?.performNotificationDefaultAction()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

If you wanna handover notification to parent app when user taps on anywhere in custom UI (not just on stars) you can override `hitTest` or `pointInside` and run the same statement :D

```
self.extensionContext?.performNotificationDefaultAction()
```

Hope it helps people who stumble upon similar problem in future :)

Comment: Hello. I have similar kinds of problems. When User tap like 2 star. Response goes to server without open the parent app. Thats working fine. The problem is I want to remove this notification. I used dismissNotificationContentExtension() Which only hide the notification. But did not remove the notification. How could I remove the notification without opening parent app?

Comment: @shourob-datta: Hey the question above deals with a little different problem then what you have asked here, I was actually trying to open the parent app and Handover the user selection (number of stars selected) but in your case you are trying to close notification without opening parent app at all so they aren't the same problem :|  I don't have much of an idea as to how to solve your problem but have you tried `removeDeliveredNotifications` or `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` ? Please don't mind if they don't work I have not dealt with this issue before :|

Comment: take a look at https://medium.com/@sebastianosiski/implementing-removable-remote-notifications-on-ios-a17d74832bde removable notifications